# How large should messages in an event queue be?

Tags: microservices, event-handling

I am working on a system where I am planning to send a large amount of data in a message to an event queue. About 150 or so small objects. I know the technology should be able to handle this, but is it good practice?

Comment: In this generality, there is no inherent limit. Perhaps more details would be fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aim is to allow recipients of the message to do thing without asking more questions.

If you can do this then your system overall is decentralised and you can reap the benefits of multiple independent processors of messages.

What you are trying to avoid is a system where the message contains only an Id which the processor has to immediately query a central db to get the full information for. As this gives you the bottleneck that you are trying to avoid.

Now obviously you have to make a judgement on how much is too much. say I've got a password change event which I want to send emails to the customer, "did you just change your password?" off the back of.

I don't want to just have the customerId, as this would mean it was useless for any purpose without a lookup, but I don't want to include the customers whole order history, just in case a hypothetical processor might need it either.

Use the same business objects that you use in your code. They should already be rightsized

Answer (score 2):

The main consideration should be whether the message contents can and should be processed in one step/transaction. If the 150 objects are independent, put them into separate messages so you can easily handle failures per object and possibly scale up by running multiple workers. If these 150 objects are some kind of parameter list for some function, keep them in one message, of course.